# Accessing git repositories with redmine, permissions problem

Tags: git, redmine, gitolite

I have Ubuntu 10.04 server with redmine installed and also git is installed, I am using gitolite.

When I push to the server from users PC, all is ok, concerning git point of view. However to see the repository from redmine, every time I need to run: `chmod o+rw -R /path/to/the/repository/folder` and then I can see the repository from redmine. But this in annoying to do it every time I push to the server.

I thought to make a cron-job to do it automatically, however I don't think is a clean solution.

Comment: have you initialized your bare repository with `--shared`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git config core.sharedRepository all
```

From the [`git-config` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> When `group` (or `true`), the repository is made shareable between several users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are group-writable). When `all` (or `world` or `everybody`), the repository will be readable by all users, additionally to being group-shareable. When `umask` (or `false`), git will use permissions reported by umask(2). When `0xxx`, where `0xxx` is an octal number, files in the repository will have this mode value. `0xxx` will override user’s umask value (whereas the other options will only override requested parts of the user’s umask value). Examples: `0660` will make the repo read/write-able for the owner and group, but inaccessible to others (equivalent to `group` unless umask is e.g. `0022`). `0640` is a repository that is group-readable but not group-writable. See git-init(1). False by default.

Comment: shall I run this on the server or on my PC and then push it on the server?

Comment: No just on the repository on the server. Configuration settings only apply locally.

Comment: OK I have done this on the repository on the server, however there is the same error 500 I get (`The entry or revision was not found in the repository.`) when I try to see the repository form redmine. I have also check the folder permission which are: `drwx------ 7 git git 4096 2011-03-05 20:09 myproject.git` and I think is not ok...

Comment: It might not take effect immediately, i.e. you may want to set the permissions manually first, then push and check if they stayed the same.

Answer (score 4):

To give Redmine access to all gitolite-hosted repositories, you need to modify `$HOME/.gitolite.rc`:

```
$REPO_UMASK = 0027; #=> 'rwxr-x---'
# use 0022 instead to give rx permissions to others (not recommended)
```

then add user running the web server hosting redmine to 'gitolite' group

At last, do `chmod -R g+rx $HOME/repositories`

See more doc at [Gitolite "`rc`" file](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rc.html).

Comment: Hey do you know if I set branch level permissions in Gitolite for certain users if the same rules/restrictions will apply für Redmine?